# Different proxy_cache_valid depending on request_uri for nginx

Tags: nginx, caching, reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx as a cache for googleapis.com. Currently all responses are cached for 5m:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/xxx_cache keys_zone=xxx_cache:10m;

server {
  location ~ /blog/ {
    proxy_pass https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/;
    proxy_cache xxx_cache;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_valid 5m;
}
```

I'd like to change this interval depending on the request_uri. Defining a `$proxy_cache_valid` variable via the `map` directive, and using it for `proxy_cache_valid`  fails with `invalid time value "$proxy_cache_valid" in ...`.

```
map $request_uri $proxy_cache_valid { 
  default 5m;
  ~^/blog/[0-9]+/posts/[0-9]+ 1h;
}

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/xxx_cache keys_zone=xxx_cache:10m;

server {
  location ~ /blog/ {
    proxy_pass https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/;
    proxy_cache xxx_cache;
    proxy_cache_lock on;
    proxy_cache_valid $proxy_cache_valid;
}
```

How can I realise this in nginx (`nginx version: nginx/1.16.1`)?

Comment: Were you able to solve this one. I am hitting the same issue.